# Почему при получении токена вконтакте, я не могу отправить сообщение с другого компьютера?

Tags: json, vkontakte-api, валидация, token

Я создал Standalone приложение. Получил токен. Отправляю сообщение на том же компьютере и IP- всё работает.
Копирую токен и пытаюсь с им отправить сообщение с другого места и получаю Error 17.
Можно ли отправлять сообщения с другого компьютера, имея токен и сбросится ли он, если пользователь сменит пароль?

Comment: Токен привязан к IP, которому выдан, поэтому не работает. Сбросится должен, просто запросите новый - если приложение не удалено и разрешения всё ещё действуют, токен выдадут.

Comment: @Other получается, если пользователь с ноутом поехал в другое место- там другой IP- то работать не будет?

Comment: Я не эксперт по работе с VK API, но разве не сервер запрашивает данные и хранит токены приложения в тайне?